# Which JRE am I really using?

Tags: java, tomcat

I try to set environment variables JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME.

JAVA_HOME worked through typing -java version in cmd but I have trouble to 
find a solution for JRE_HOME.

```
javac version
```

doesn't work

```
java-XshowSettings:properties -version
```

doesn't work either[image]

Comment: Have you set JRE_HOME variable? What is its value? (`echo %JRE_HOME%`)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: it echoes jre1.8.0_202

Answer (score 0):

When updating environment variables in windows make sure to open a new terminal session. The old terminal session will not have the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set JAVA_HOME=jre in jdk folder

then do not close the command promt,

then do startup.bat

Comment: setting it in the terminal or setting it as an environmental variable in windows?

Comment: setting in in terminal works for that session only and as environment variable for permanently.